# Xcode 4 automatic code completion -- how to insert NO into code

Tags: xcode4, code-completion

If I try to type NO into my code somewhere, it brings up a completion list.  The highlighted item in the list is always "noisy", which is a variable that frequently appears in my code.  Then I have to move to the right item in the list, because if I hit enter it will insert "noisy".

Is there a simple way to insert NO into my code?

Comment: Tap the escape key.
It's that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just hit space after typing NO, instead of enter. It looks confusing because you see the word you don't want there; but if you hit space, it will revert to just the characters you typed.

Comment: and give me some whitespace I don't want :(  Still a good solution, thanks.